# Get key details from the value through grep

Tags: perl, grep, hashmap

I am trying to find the key name as output by matching `$country_value` variable in `grep` through the hash I have.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $country_value = 1;

my $country = {
    'IN' => [
              1,
              5
            ],
    'US' => [
              2,
              6
            ],
    'UK' => [
              3,
              7
            ]
};

my $country_details = grep { $_ eq $country_value } values %{$country};

print $country_details;

print "\n";
```

As per the hash, I need to get the output as `IN` because the value of `IN` is `1` and the `$country_value` is `1`, which is what I am trying to find out.

But, I get the output as `0` instead of `IN`.

Can someone please help?

Comment: You could use [`List::Util::any`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#any) like this: `grep { any { $_ eq $country_value } @{$country->{$_} } } keys %$country`

Comment: You don't need both `-w` and `use warnings` (as they basically do the same thing). Most people just use `use warnings`.

Comment: Using `-w` is generally discouraged. See https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings#What's-wrong-with-w-and-$%5EW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `values` returns a reference to an array.  You need to dereference that to get a list for `grep`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $country_value = 1;

my $country = {
    'IN' => [
              1,
              5
            ],
    'US' => [
              2,
              6
            ],
    'UK' => [
              3,
              7
            ]
};

my $country_details;
for my $name (keys %{$country}) {
    if (grep { $_ == $country_value } @{ $country->{$name} }) {
        $country_details = $name;
        last;
    }
}
print $country_details, "\n";
```

Prints:

```
IN
```